# How do I remove properties from JavaScript object in array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-8

Let say I have this array as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 111,
        "productName": "Chicken",
        "variant": 9,
        "variantName": "small",
        "extrasSelected": [],
        "price": 26,
        "qty": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 112,
        "productName": "Fish",
        "variant": 25,
        "variantName": "small",
        "extrasSelected": [],
        "price": 26,
        "qty": "1"
    }
]
```

How do I remove some of the properties so it will end up as follows?

```
[
  {
     "id": 111,
     "variant": 9,
     "extrasSelected": [],
     "qty": "1"
  },
  {
     "id": 112,
     "variant": 25,
     "extrasSelected": [],
     "qty": "1"
  }
]
```

The reasons why I need to do so, because I need to send the `newObject` data into my `finalCart`, but I need the `productName` in `oldObject` to display it on my view.

Comment: You can use the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: Time to study the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and [Array.Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.
If you actually want to `delete` the properties, here is one way:

```js
let array = [
    {
        "id": 111,
        "productName": "Chicken",
        "variant": 9,
        "variantName": "small",
        "extrasSelected": [],
        "price": 26,
        "qty": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 112,
        "productName": "Fish",
        "variant": 25,
        "variantName": "small",
        "extrasSelected": [],
        "price": 26,
        "qty": "1"
    }
]

array.forEach(obj => {
  delete obj.variantName;  
  delete obj.price;
  delete obj.productName;
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! This is the easiest for me to implement it in my code ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.map`

```
[
    {
        "id": 111,
        "productName": "Chicken",
        "variant": 9,
        "variantName": "small",
        "extrasSelected": [],
        "price": 26,
        "qty": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 112,
        "productName": "Fish",
        "variant": 25,
        "variantName": "small",
        "extrasSelected": [],
        "price": 26,
        "qty": "1"
    }
].map(({id, variant, extrasSelected, qty}) => ({id, variant, extrasSelected, qty}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do a destructuring inside a `.map`

```
const data = [
  {
    "id": 111,
    "productName": "Chicken",
    "variant": 9,
    "variantName": "small",
    "extrasSelected": [],
    "price": 26,
    "qty": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 112,
    "productName": "Fish",
    "variant": 25,
    "variantName": "small",
    "extrasSelected": [],
    "price": 26,
    "qty": "1"
  }
];

// 1
const result = data.map(({ id, variant, extrasSelected, qty }) => ({
  id,
  variant,
  extrasSelected,
  qty
}));

// Detailed explanation

// 2
// 2 is same as 1
const result2 = data.map((item => {
  const { id, variant, extrasSelected, qty } = item;
  return { id, variant, extrasSelected, qty };
}));

// 3
// 3 is same as 2
const result3 = data.map((item) => {
  const id = item.id;
  const variant = item.variant;
  const extrasSelected = item.extrasSelected;
  const qty = item.qty;

  return {
    id: id,
    variant: variant,
    extrasSelected: extrasSelected,
    qty: qty
  }
});

console.log(result);

/*

[
  { id: 111, variant: 9, extrasSelected: [], qty: '1' },
  { id: 112, variant: 25, extrasSelected: [], qty: '1' }
]

*/
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for you detailed explanation! :)

Answer (score 2):

Variation on the above solutions. Use `Array.Map` and rest parameters.

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 111,
    "productName": "Chicken",
    "variant": 9,
    "variantName": "small",
    "extrasSelected": [],
    "price": 26,
    "qty": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 112,
    "productName": "Fish",
    "variant": 25,
    "variantName": "small",
    "extrasSelected": [],
    "price": 26,
    "qty": "1"
  }
]

const result = data.map(({
  productName,
  variantName,
  ...rest
}) => rest);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! New knowledge has been added :D

Comment: No worries. All the best.